# Hibernate Scrollabe Results

Tags: hibernate

Presently I am trying to read huge data from database using Hibernate .I am using scrollable results as an iterator but the problem is, its not reading directly from the database but first it is putting the data in the ram and then reading which is affecting the performance.One of the solution that came to my mind was to increase the heap space but if anyone has any other better solution please share.

Thanx

Comment: Take a look at various strategies http://java.dzone.com/articles/bulk-fetching-hibernate